# Extended WPF Toolkit - How to add reference to project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, dll, wpftoolkit

I am new to WPF. I want to use datetime picker. I have downloaded the "Extended WPF Toolkit - 1.9.0" from below site.

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/96972

I have unzip file and found two dll. One is "WPFToolkit.dll" and "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll".

Now How to add these two dll in my project? and
How to use datetime control in my project.

Comment: Put them in a convenient place and then right-click the ToolBox, Choose Items.

Comment: I have added the both .ddl reference to by project. But how to use these .dll code in my project. I mean to say how to add xmlns link in my page? Please help me.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First, reference those dlls in your project.
Right click on `References` in the Solution Explorer and click `Add Reference`, now browse and add the two dlls.

Second, build the project once to enable intellisense in XAML for the newly added dlls.

Third, in your XAML file add the following namespace

```
    xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
```

Tip: Type `xmlns:customName="wpftool"` and you should be able to see the intellisense list all the relevant namespaces.

Heres the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <wpfTool:DateTimePicker Grid.Row="0">

        </wpfTool:DateTimePicker>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Its a Grate. You relay saved me. Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 11):

Graphical Way to add the controls in VS 2013

1. First, reference those dlls in your project.
2. Right click on References in the Solution Explorer and click Add Reference, now browse and add the two dlls.
3. Right Click to toolbox > General Area and Choose "Add Tab" - Give the name to the Tab say "WPF Toolkit Controls"!
4. Now Clcik on Choose Items..It opens choose toolbox Items dialog box...!
5. In WPF Component tab - Now Click on Browse button and locate the downloaded dll and click on open
6. WPF Component Tab will show all the control
7. By Clicking on OK "WPF Toolkit Controls" will populate all the controls of the WPF Toolkit
8. Now Drag and Drop the Required Control - It will automatically add the namespace reference required.

Answer (score 10):

Installation Extended Toolkit using NuGet

```
Install NuGet  
Open your Visual Studio.  
Open your solution/project.  
Open Tools menu, select Library Package Manager and select Package Manager Console
Run the following command "Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit"
```

then try you will get the namespace.

[NuGet package page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit) (available since 17 June 2016)

Answer (score 4):

In XAML you should add:

For AvalonDock:

```
xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
```

For WPF Toolkit:

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to the method you are currently using, right-click on your project then choose Add Reference. Go to Browse and locate the dlls you downloaded.

or

Download NuGet [here](http://nuget.org/).
It's much easier to install third-party libraries.

Comment: I have added the both .ddl reference to by project. But how to use these .dll code in my project. I mean to say how to add xmlns link in my page? Please help me.