# Error in Visual Studio 2017 trying to reference the WPF Extended Toolkit in XAML

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am attempting to use the WPF Extended Toolkit. I downloaded it and it is currently sitting in my project folder.

[image: project folder]

I right clicked the .dll file and checked "Unblock" following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387163/the-type-toolkitbusyindicator-was-not-found) answer. I have it referenced in my Visual Studio project.

[image: References]

I have it named WPF Extended Toolkit in my Toolbox.

[image: Toolbox]

I have the namespace in my XAML file.

[image: namespace]

When I try to use it in my XAML file, I'm getting the blue squiggly line stating, "The type toolkit:BusyIndicator was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built."

[image: Error]

I'm very new to this, since I've only used what was available by default in WPF apps. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I thought I covered everything needed to get this going.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809446/extended-wpf-toolkit-how-to-add-reference-to-project/28429557)!

**Before** adding the namespace, I rebuilt my project, **then** I added the namespace. IntelliSense picked it up and I was able to add my Busy Indicator.